# How to pass the roles of a http session to a websocket?

Tags: java, session, tomcat, websocket

In my situation (tomcat) I use tomcat-users.xml to manage the link between users and roles

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <role rolename="role2"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat" username="tomcat"/>
    <user password="123456" roles="role1,role2" username="user1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

and web.xml is configured like that:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.WebSocketServletListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Tomcat Server Configuration Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>     
      <url-pattern>/application.jsp</url-pattern>           
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>role1</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Cloud Authentication</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

The connection to the application has two steps:

1. I log my application via 'login.jsp' referring me to the single page of my application 'application.jsp'. In application.jsp I can know roles of the user connected with request.isUserInRole("role1");
2. application.jsp opens a WebSocket with the server and the webSocket create a session.java. All communications will be done through the WebSocket. The problem is in the context of the webSocket I don't know the roles of my user.

What is the best way to recover all user information in the session of the webSocket?

Answer (score 0):

A WebSockets connection starts with a normal HTTP request/response, so you should be able to glean all the relevant user details from that as normal.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to do it in Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are using in your JSP, if you are using the Tomcat Websocket class, when you use

```
createWebSocketInbound

protected abstract StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol,
                                                        HttpServletRequest request)
```

you can read the `HttpServletRequest request`, you should be able to get all the handshake data and map the connection to the user. It should have the same context as the JSP request, but for additional security you should probably handle the `HttpServletRequest request` directly in the code you write to handle the webSocket connection.

Comment: I have still a problem... How can I get all roles of a user from the request. I can check if he has a role with 'isUserInRole' but I don't know how to do 'getAllRoles'. The idea is to set all roles of the user connected to a variable 'roles' of a class instance 'UserConnected'

Comment: get all roles isn't supported in the servlet spec. you really have to know what roles you need ahead of time. Roles can be mapped to other roles via web.xml

Comment: @Axel can you elaborate on which tomcat websocket class you are referring to?

Comment: If it's `org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet` that's deprecated per docs, `Deprecated. Replaced by the JSR356 WebSocket 1.1 implementation and will be removed in Tomcat 8.0.x.`